# Unpinning Tile updates information in object in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have an object which contains one boolean property `IsPinnedToStart`. This property is set to true when the user creates a secondary tile from the main application. This property is set to false when the user unpins the tile from main application.

But, when i unpin the tile from Start, the property is not updated otherwise.

So my main question is how do i get notified in application when i unpin the secondary tile from Start Screen?

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanx in advance ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.  You should query all the tiles that your app has created in the start screen (in the ShellTile.ActiveTiles collection), and determine from there whether the current content item is pinned or not.

for example, to delete a tile linking to a specific item id...

```
var tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.Single(t => t.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("?ItemId=" + MyItemId));
tile.Delete();
```

or to determine if there is a tile for a specific  item id...

```
bool tileExists = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.Where(t => t.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("?ItemId=" + MyItemId)).Any();
```

note : Code untested, and based on a blog post [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pavely/archive/2011/09/30/dynamic-live-tiles-in-windows-phone-7.aspx)

Comment: So this means, whenever i open my application... I have to make synchronization check with respect to IsPinnedToStart property... Right?

Comment: I'm afraid so, yes.  It is probably best to do this every time you navigate to a page that has pin or unpin functionality to maintain the state of the start screen - a user can press the start button from your app and unpin a tile, then navigate back.